# If I have the xpath of a button on a webpage, how can I put a box around that specific element?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have a python application that is scraping the HTML from a live webpage and parsing through it. I am getting a return of the xpaths for everything that has an href. With the xpaths I am getting, is there a way to put a box/border around the specific element that is linked to the xpath?

```
  browser = 
    webdriver.Chrome("")



    browser.get("http://www.dominos.com")
    browser.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')





    tags = soup.find_all('a')
    check = soup.find('Delivery')
    print(check)
    href_set = []



    for tag in tags:

        xpath = xpath_soup(tag)
        href_set.append([tag.get('href'),tag.getText(), xpath])



    for i in range(len(href_set)):
        print(href_set[i])




    browser.close()
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to find the element.

Comment: @Jortega
Here is an example of what one of the xpath results I am getting: /html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[2]/main[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]

Comment: It's my understanding that Beautiful soup is typically used for parsing pages and if you want to serve up modified pages you will need something like django or pyramid.

Comment: @kpie So, if I actually changed the html by adding style to wherever the specific xpath is linked, I would be able to do it? Also, now that I have the xpaths I don't really need to use Beautiful Soup again. Just trying to get an idea of how I can use these xpaths to show what element they are linked to on a page.

Comment: Yeah I mean you can't modify what for example google will provide at a particular url but you can run a host that will serve modified content. Just be careful about monopolization and such... Generally speaking re-publishing modified content is copyright infringement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `browser.execute_script()` to execute a javascript function to add red box around what you are looking for. I am assuming you have selenium setup some where outside the code you shared.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://www.dominos.com")
browser.maximize_window()
someelement = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[2]/main[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]")
red_border = "border: 2px solid red;"
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", someelement , red_border )
time.sleep(10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
tags = soup.find_all('a')
check = soup.find('Delivery')
print(check)
href_set = []
for tag in tags:
    xpath = xpath_soup(tag)
    href_set.append([tag.get('href'),tag.getText(), xpath])
for i in range(len(href_set)):
    print(href_set[i])
browser.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, this does what is intended.

Comment: @Jortega I have removed the blank spaces and lines from your code and indented your code. Please have a look at the formatted code block to confirm if it look good.